# How to reference range in multiple sheets in VBA countif function?

Tags: excel, vba, loops, countif

Vba beginner here. I have workbook named "Dane" in which I have worksheets, where each must be searched for specific rows. These rows can't contain values from A column from my macro workbook and will be highlighted with "1" in specific column. I used nested loops - outside for worksheets, inside for rows. The problem is: 1's show only in first sheet. When i add 'Dane.Worksheets(i).' before 'prodRange(x, 1)' error "object doesn't support property or method" occurs.

```
Dim Dane As Workbook
Set Dane = Workbooks("something.xlsx")
Dim prodRange As Range
Set prodRange = Range("A18:I92")

For i = 4 To 23
       Dane.Worksheets(i).Activate
       For x = 2 To 75
         If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Top").Range("A:A"), prodRange(x, 1)) = 0 Then
         prodRange(x, 1).Offset(0, 17) = 1
         End If
       Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you:

> `Set prodRange = Range("A18:I92")`

The parent sheet is set.  It is set to the sheet that is active at the time that the object is set.

So move it into the first loop.

```
Dim Dane As Workbook
Set Dane = Workbooks("something.xlsx")

For i = 4 To 23
    Dim prodRange As Range
    Set prodRange = Dane.Worksheets(i).Range("A18:I92")
    For x = 2 To 75
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Top").Range("A:A"), prodRange(x, 1)) = 0 Then
        prodRange(x, 1).Offset(0, 17) = 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```